# Select n items starting with each alphabet from a-z in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have tried asking this question previously but moderators closed the question citing it as not clear. Hope this time I make it clear.

I've a services table with up to 1000 services. The table has id & service_title column. So, I basically want to get 10 services each for each alphabet starting from A to Z. If there are fewer than 10 items starting with any particular alphabet than I want to get them all. Also I want them in alphabetical order if possible.

Here's my services table.

[image]

So my output table should look something like the one displayed below. For the sake of simplicity I've shown 2 services starting with each alphabet from A to J.

```html
<table border="1">
 <caption>Services</caption>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Auditing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Accounting</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Brick laying</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>Builders</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>Carpet Cleaning</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>Carpenters</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>7</td>
   <td>Demolition</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>8</td>
   <td>Dog Walking</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>9</td>
   <td>Electrician</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>10</td>
   <td>Equipment Hire</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>11</td>
   <td>Fencing & Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>12</td>
   <td>Fright Services</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>13</td>
   <td>Gardeners</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>14</td>
   <td>Gate keepers</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>15</td>
   <td>Handyman</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>16</td>
   <td>Health service</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>17</td>
   <td>Interview Trainer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>18</td>
   <td>Iterpersonal Relationship Coach</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>19</td>
   <td>Joinery Experts</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>20</td>
   <td>Jacket Maker</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the code I've come up with till now

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT id, service_title,
    @count := IF(@value = service_title, @count + 1, 1) AS count
    FROM services, (SELECT @count := 1, @value := NULL) a
    WHERE services.service_title REGEXP  '^[A-z]+$'
    ) a
WHERE a.count <= 10
Order by service_title
```

I've listed some services in my sample output table which are not listed in the sample items on the table image, please do not raise that as as issue as I can't display all items on the sample table image.

Comment: You should add your table definition, some sample data and the code you have so far. You don't need a lot of data 2 of each for a 3 (a-c) would be plenty. You should also add the code you have attempted otherwise it just looks like you are asking for us to do your job for you.AND what version of mysql are you on.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. How do you want to select the 10 services for each letter? randomly? by `id`? what if there aren't 10 services for a given letter?

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry I forgot to add my code. I'm not just trying to search for someone to do my work for free. That's not simply me. I have updated the question with the code so far I've come up with but I'm not getting the result I'm looking for. My MySQL version is 5.7.29

Comment: @Nick I've updated the question with more info please have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below query with minor updates from your query -

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id,
             @count := IF(LEFT(@value, 1) = LEFT(service_title, 1), @count + 1, 1) AS cnt,
             @value := service_title service_title
    FROM services, (SELECT @count := 0, @value := 0) vars
    WHERE services.service_title REGEXP  '^[A-z]+'
    ORDER BY service_title, id
    ) a
WHERE a.cnt <= 10
Order by service_title, id
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e4f6e/10)

Comment: Thanks for your effort Ankit. I tried using your query with minor tweaks but still it didn't give the result I was looking for. You can see the output of the query in the image in this link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kIveP-4EjcVHavlcYDIBhZ0JKb7xMEUw

Comment: @RajanAcharya, Please try now.

Comment: Thnaks for ur effort Ankit. But that still didn't produce the result I was searching for. It still produced result very similar to the last one. Here's the link to the sqlfiddle I created: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e4f6e/1

Comment: @RajanAcharya, There was an issue in your regular expression. I have corrected that attached the fiddle demo also. Please let me know if you still have an issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution worked like magic. Really appreciate your effort. I really have been stuck on it for many days now.